# Camel Elasticsearch Component throws Connection refused

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I'm using latest Camel 3.17 on Camel-K with [Elasticsearch REST Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/elasticsearch-rest-component.html) and Elastic 7.7 instance all on Kubernetes Cluster with Services.

I'm getting Connection refused when running a simple integration with this Route:

```java
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

import org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchComponent;

public class Routes extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        ElasticsearchComponent elasticsearchComponent = new ElasticsearchComponent();
        elasticsearchComponent.setHostAddresses("elasticsearch-rlam-service:9200");
        getContext().addComponent("elasticsearch-rest", elasticsearchComponent);

        from("kafka:dbz?brokers={{kafka.bootstrap.address}}&groupId=apps&autoOffsetReset=earliest")
            .choice()
                .when().simple("${body} == 'null'")
                    .log("Null!")
                .otherwise()
                    .log("Message: ${body}")
                    .to("elasticsearch-rest://elasticsearch?hostAddresses=elasticsearch-rlam-service:9200&operation=INDEX&indexName=dbz")
            .endChoice();
    }
}
```

The call for ElasticSearchComponent is not mandatory for this test since I'm not connecting through port 9300 with credentials, but still removing it and adding `hostAddresses` property doesn't resolve this issue.

The stacktrace:

```
2022-06-20 00:11:35,837 INFO [route1] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[dbz]) Null!
2022-06-20 00:11:35,849 INFO [route1] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[dbz]) Message: {"last_name":"Ketchmar","id":1004,"first_name":"Anne","email":"annek@noanswer.org"}
2022-06-20 00:11:36,116 ERROR [org.apa.cam.pro.err.DefaultErrorHandler] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[dbz]) Failed delivery for (MessageId: 274D73D47B2829F-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: 274D73D47B2829F-0000000000000000). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Message History (source location and message history is disabled)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source ID Processor Elapsed (ms)
route1/route1 from[kafka://dbz?autoOffsetReset=earliest&brokers= 272
...
route1/to1 elasticsearch-rest://elasticsearch?hostAddresses=e 0
Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:918)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:299)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:287)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1632)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1602)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1572)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:989)
at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.process(ElasticsearchProducer.java:170)
at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:172)
at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:471)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:193)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:64)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:184)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:399)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41)
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.consumer.support.KafkaRecordProcessor.processExchange(KafkaRecordProcessor.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.consumer.support.KafkaRecordProcessorFacade.processRecord(KafkaRecordProcessorFacade.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.consumer.support.KafkaRecordProcessorFacade.processPolledRecords(KafkaRecordProcessorFacade.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaFetchRecords.startPolling(KafkaFetchRecords.java:280)
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaFetchRecords.run(KafkaFetchRecords.java:181)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
... 1 more
```

I've tried reaching ES from another pod and it works just fine

Comment: Is it possible you need to `enableSSL`? According to the doc [1], it's disabled by default. [1] https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/elasticsearch-rest-component.html

Comment: Are you sure that the `elasticsearch-rlam-service:9200` is reachable from within your Camel Route hosting container? Have you had the respective k8s service configured?